# Ajuda? Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, bootstrap

Estou com esse erro e já tentei de tudo, mas nada aqui o erro:

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).tooltip is not a function TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
        at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://askmee.tk/zero0:54:34)
        at j (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
        at k (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js:2:30313)
    undefined
        r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.min.js:2
        k @ jquery.min.js:2
        setTimeout (async)
        (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2
        i @ jquery.min.js:2
        fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
        fire @ jquery.min.js:2
        i @ jquery.min.js:2
        fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
        ready @ jquery.min.js:2
        S @ jquery.min.js:3
        jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
            at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (zero0:54)
            at j (jquery.min.js:2)
            at k (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Código:

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    });
</script>

echo "<a data-id=\"{$answer['ask_hash']}\" data-toggle=\"tooltip\" title=\"Like\" onclick=\"like.add('{$to_id->login}','{$answer['ask_hash']}',false); return false;\" href=\"/{$to_id->login}/answer/{$answer['ask_hash']}/like\" class=\"ask-like $promt\"><i class=\"like\"></i></a>";
```

Comment: Parece que esse `tooltip` não pertence nem ao jQuery nem ao Bootstrap, então você precisa incluir o arquivo desta biblioteca também.

Comment: Está utilizando o [jQuery-UI](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/)? Também, abriste a tag PHP (<?php) para utilizar echo?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss eu peguei foi no site e mostrava a funciona tudo certo.

Comment: @Stormwind Sim botei o (<?php) no echo eu so cortei código pra simplifica, o jQuery lá não sei se UI você pode certificar pra min esta link do proprio google que leva a ele

Comment: Se é deste [`tooltip`](http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/) que está dizendo, ele pertence ao jQuery UI, então precisa incluir a biblioteca dele...

Comment: Então, você deveria saber de qual jQuery está usando :P. Existem dois tooltips, nos links http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/#entry-examples e  https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/, qual dos dois você está usando? @Megatorial

Comment: O Bootstrap possui um `tooltip` como esse, mas no seu caso você está inicializando um elemento que ainda não foi carregado na sua página, coloque o script em baixo do `echo` e teste